# Помогите pyTelegramBotAPI [Пересылка]

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот

Есть бот, мне нужно чтобы от писал мне сообщение и тег юзера.
Пробовал методом вывода мне message.from_user.username, но вместо юзера пользователя отправляет @None.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=('start'))
def start(message):
    pass1 = f'Привет, зарегистрировался новый пользователь @{message.from_user.username}'
    --- (Тут идут кнопки)
    --- (Тут идут кнопки)
    --- (Тут идут кнопки)
    bot.send_message(XXXXXXXXX, pass1, parse_mode='html')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если есть возможность, подскажите как сделать чтобы кидало ссылку на аккаунт на случай если не будет юзернейма

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Не у всех пользователей телеги есть username. Вы уверены, что это не тот случай?

Comment: Уверен, я проверял со своего аккаунта где есть юзернейм

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем я решил вопрос

```
bot.send_message(XXXXXXX, 'Зарегестрирован новый [{}](tg://user?id={})  '
                     .format('ВАШ ТЕКСТ',
                             message.from_user.id), disable_web_page_preview=True,
                     parse_mode='Markdown')
```

где **XXXXXXX** указываем свой ID аккаунта, Где написано **ВАШ ТЕКСТ** пишем любой текст, будет подставляться в текст ссылка на аккаунт, *если вы хотите сделать чтобы показывало только имя  нужно быть уверенным что у человека не стоит фамилия, если Имя и Фамилию то должны быть уверенны что у человека не стоит только имя.*